# How can I get the document root using the storage API?

Tags: content-delivery

I'm looking at an old implementation that makes use of:

broker.getDocumentRoot(publicationId)

where broker is the instance of com.tridion.broker.Broker

This is deprecated, and also relies on having `cd_broker_conf.xml`, which we'd rather not. The storage API offers the possibility of accessing the current configuration, but that seems like re-implementing code that is probably already in Tridion. Is there a straightforward way to get the document root?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a way to get the configuration file root directly in Tridion Storage API (or Storage Extension). I have working out it with below code (sample is from Storage Extension):

```
    private String GetConfigFilePath()
    {
        String _configFilePath;

        //code to pick config file from appropriate path
        CodeSource codeSource = this.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();

        File jarFile = null;

        try 
        {
            jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        } 
        catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String configFileDir = jarFile.getParentFile().getPath();
        log.debug("Configuration file directory is: " + configFileDir);

        _configFilePath = configFileDir + "<configFileName>.xml";
        log.info("ConfigFilePath: " + _configFilePath);
        return _configFilePath;
    }
```

I hope this may help.